# Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine после перезапуска сервера

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb

Сегодня вечером мой сервер завис и перезапустился, после чего одна из табличек пострадала, и перестала работать.
Бекапа к сожалению нет.

Файлы `mytable.ibd` и `mytable.frm` есть, и права на них верные.

`ibdata1` и `ib_logfile*` тоже существуют и не пострадали.

При попытке взаимодействия с табличкой получаю:
`Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine`

В системном логе вот это:
`[ERROR] InnoDB: Table mydb.mytable contains unrecognizable instant ALTER metadata`

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

MariaDB 10.4.8

Не подскажете что случилось с табличкой и можно ли ее восстановить ?

Comment: из гугла: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло...
При попытке получения данных из таблицы я получаю Unknown error 1877